# Toggle visibility of fxml fx-include

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

how can I show/hide an included (fx-include) control?

```
<fx:include fx:id="testCaseComboboxUI" source="TestCaseComboboxUI.fxml" visible="false" managed="false"/>
```

I would like to show or hide the above conditionally. Something like `testCaseComboboxUI.setVisible(true)`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was able to find the answer

```
@FXML private Parent testCaseComboboxUI;
```

[Reference](http://blog.buildpath.de/fxml-composition-how-to-get-the-controller-of-an-included-fxml-view-nested-controllers/)